Identifying a distribution of numbers that may be related to a Dirichlet Distribution
I'm creating 3-tuples through the following process: let $x_1$, $x_2$ and $x_3$ be independently sampled from a uniform distribution on $[0,1]$, and let $y_i = x_i/(x_1+x_2+x_3)$. Using Mathematica, I accomplish this via:
point=RandomReal[1,3];
point=point/Total[point]

When I plot a set of these points, I get a distinct-looking distribution of points on the plane $z=1-x-y$, as seen below.  Projecting these points into the $x$-$y$ plane, we get the following. 
What is the name of the distribution these points seem to be following? In doing some searching, it seems the points should be following a Dirichlet Distribution, but my attempts at recreating points sampled from such a distribution do not match what I see in the images. (I'm using the Mathematica command
RandomVariate[DirichletDistribution[{1, 1, 1}], 10000]
which creates a uniform distribution of points in the $x$-$y$ plane.)
So, I have two questions:

What is the name of the distribution my points seems to be following?
If the distribution is truly a Dirichlet Distribution, what are the proper parameters to exhibit the behavior I see?


It is not a Dirichlet distribution.  If it were, then the marginal distribution of $y_1$ would be a Beta distribution, and if you plot the density of $y$ from your sample, it is clearly not.
